# How Can I Access Platform Resources (android.R.layout) from XML Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Can I create a `TextView` based on **android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1** in my XML layout and specify  only extra attributes like

```
<TextView  based on android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
android:text="Some text"/>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about how you can access platform resources in XML files, I believe this is what you want :

```
 <include layout="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1" />
```

You can then customize this item by adding attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean clearly
you can set your extra attributes like below ?

```
<TextView  based on android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
android:text="@string/name"/>
```

and then in your code:

```
String name = getResoures.getStringResoures(R.string.name);
```

Comment: I mean to use all attributes from android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
and setup only attributes that have not specific values in android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1

Comment: you can set special attributes using like Textview.setText();  but you can't let android system to find which attributes you haven't set

Comment: I know which attributes are set in android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1. I do not  know how to tell android system to use those attributes when it will build my textview. And I'd like to tell it in XML file not in code.

Comment: give your textview an id, and then just find your textview use findViewById() method, android will use those attributes when build it

Comment: To assign id is not a problem. I want to build my textview based on simple_list_item_1. It is like to extend classes in Java. I know how to extend simple_list_item_1 in Java code. But I do not know how to do it in XML. That is the question.

Comment: i finally know what you mean.... and till now i find no solution to build an textview based on another in xml, but you can try to save values you may use in both textview xml

Comment: To save values is not a big deal. But I do not like to check from time to time if the definition of simple_list_item_1 is changed or not.

Comment: i mean you can save values (height, width, etc) in an xml file , both textview make a reference to it

Comment: As far as I understand the definition of simple_list_item_1 is managed by android, isn't it? If it is true than I could not change the definition of simple_list_item_1 to please my local project.

Comment: sorry, i can't help you any more , i'll try to find if there are any solutions to it